# Ubuntu, how to edit interface settings

Tags: networking

how to edit interface settings on a virtual Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You do it the same as in any Ubuntu machine.. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the interfaces file using something like:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: you also have to run `sudo ifdown -a && sudo ifup -a` to make changes take effect

Comment: Yep, forgot to include this. You can bring the interface up/down or reboot your machine.